# No space allocated for tikz picture in beamerarticle

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamerarticle

I'm creating a beamer presentation with a separate handout using the workflow describe in section 21.2.2 of the [beamer user guide](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). I use tikz for diagrams. Here are the three files:

main.beamer.tex (for the slide presentation):

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\input{main.tex}
```

main.article.tex (for the article):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\setjobnamebeamerversion{main.beamer}
\input{main.tex}
```

main.tex (for common code):

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\frame
{
  \frametitle{Title of the first slide}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \tikzstyle{every text node part} = [align=center]
    \tikzstyle{obj node} = [ellipse, fill=blue!20]
    \node[obj node] (obja) {Words in a bubble Words in a bubble \\ Words in a bubble};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
Here is some content that is shown only in the article, not in the beamer slides.
\frame
{
  \frametitle{Title of the second slide}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Foo
  \end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

The slides are created using

```
$ xelatex main.beamer.tex
```

and the article:

```
$ xelatex main.article.tex
```

The problem is that I'm getting no space allocated in the article for the picture. There's no vertical space for it, and it is aligned to the extreme left of the page, not within the normal flow of the document, as shown in the image:

[image: No room for picture in article]

How can I get vertical space for it, and change the horizontal position within the article, without affecting the beamer slides?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! At a first glance, the reason is that you define the picture as `overlay`, which exactly instructs tikz not to allocate any space.

Comment: Brilliant! That fixes it. I wonder why I had `overlay` in there. I'm learning tikz and copied that from an example. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omit the option `overlay`.

Revised `main.tex`:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.multipart}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % never seen anyone using these 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title of the first slide}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    [every text node part/.style = {align=center},
     obj node/.style = {ellipse, fill=blue!20}
    ]
    \node[obj node] (obja) {Words in a bubble Words in a bubble \\ Words in a bubble};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

Here is some content that is shown only in the article, not in the
beamer slides.

\begin{frame}{Title of the second slide}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Foo
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output of `main.beamer.tex`:

[image]

Output of `main.article.tex`:

[image]